# Complex inequality $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

My textbook says if $a$ and $b$ are two complex numbers, then $$|a+b|\le |a|+|b|,$$ and the equality holds if and only if $a\bar{b} \ge 0$.

How can we say the equality holds if and only if $a\bar b \ge 0$? I think $a\bar b$ is a complex number and complex numbers do not have order.

If we square both sides and cancel some terms, then we can see that the equality holds if Re$(a\bar b) = |a||b|$.

It is on page 9 of Ahlfors' Complex Analysis.

Comment: What they mean with "$a\bar b\geqslant0$" is that $a\bar b$ should be a nonnegative real number. Yes, this is sloppy writing.

Comment: See the parenthesis in Ahlfors immediately after this point: it is convenient to let $c>0$ indicate that $c$ is *real* and *positive*.

Comment: We can show $a\bar b$ is nonnegative real number by expanding $a\bar b$ and notice that its imaginary part is zero since we have the relation Re$(a\bar b)  = |a||b|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\operatorname{Re}(a\bar b)=|a||b|=|ab|=|a\bar b|
$$
if and only if $\operatorname{Im}(a\bar b)=0$ and $a\bar b\ge 0$, so $a\bar b$ has to be real.

Comment: If $a=1$, $b=-1$, then $\operatorname{Im}(a\bar b)=0$, but $\operatorname{Re}(a\bar b)\ne|a\bar b|$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami That's true, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality holds if and only if $|a+b|^2\le(|a|+|b|)^2$ holds, which becomes
$$
|a|^2+a\bar{b}+\bar{a}b+|b|^2\le |a|^2+2|a|\,|b|+|b|^2
$$
We can cancel real terms from both sides and still get an equivalent inequality:
$$
a\bar{b}+\bar{a}b\le2|a|\,|b| \tag{*}
$$

This surely holds and is strict if $a\bar{b}+\bar{a}b<0$ (following Ahlfors's convention that $c>0$ means that $c$ is real and positive).

Let's suppose $a\bar{b}+\bar{a}b\ge0$. Then squaring is allowed and yields an equivalent inequality:
$$
a^2\bar{b}^2+2a\bar{a}b\bar{b}+\bar{a}^2b^2\le 4a\bar{a}b\bar{b}
$$
that is, moving the (real) right-hand side to the left
$$
(a\bar{b}-\bar{a}b)^2\le0
$$
which is true, because $a\bar{b}-\bar{a}b$ is purely imaginary.

A necessary condition for having an equality is that $a\bar{b}=\bar{a}b$, that is $a\bar{b}$ is real. Together with (*) we obtain $a\bar{b}=2|a|\,|b|\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of $a$ and $b$ as being planar vectors.  Draw the parallelogram and apply the parallelogram law.  You will see the geometric meaning of this immediately.